# Django Rest Framework Angular2 UTC time zone

Tags: angular, timezone, utc, django-rest-framework

My backend is a Django Rest Framework app, my frontend is Angular 2.
When I send data from my frontend to my backend, my backend store the dates UTC formatted. My application is international, so my problem is, when a user store a date from a diferent UTC, and he consults this data after the save, the date is not correct (the bonus hours are not saved). 
What is the good way to manage UTC in this case (Backend / Frontend)?
How can I tell DRF to convert the dates in the returned JSON to the client's timezone?

Comment: Store in UTC timezone on backend and change it to users timezone on the front end side

Comment: So I need to convert to server time zone before sending datas (from my frontend)?

Comment: Yeah that would be better. It would make uniformity for the server if there are multiple client applications using your Django API